# A user was found to match all plain text credentials however hashed credential [password] did not match

Tags: php, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

With Laravel 4.1, I am able to login into my admin panel with the same user name and password. After I deployed the solution to our server, following error shows on login:

> A user was found to match all plain text credentials however hashed
>   credential [password] did not match.

Anyone faced with this please?

Comment: Does you live server have MCrypt extension?

Comment: Just installed MCrypt in our VPS server. But same error popping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the `Default Hasher` to `sha256` in the config file :

> app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry/config.php

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Meantime could there be any compromise to security with sha256?